# webpack.js error compile error Maven with Visallo

Tags: java, node.js, maven, github, networking

Trying to pull Visallo from github and compile using Maven. JDK 8 was used as Visallo recommends not using 9 . I am on windows 7

http://docs.visallo.org/getting-started.html

NodeJS was installed separately from the github pull, by installing into windows. Paths are correct for Maven & java . They *seem* correct for nodejs.

When trying to compile I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-
plugin:1.6:webpack (webpack build) on project visallo-web-product-graph: 
Failed to run task: 'webpack.js ' failed. 
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 
(Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]
```

Been trying different compile options for days and still no joy (eg clean etc)

Update (and bump) - all paths installed using but still no luck. Visallo is a great network analysis tool - it is great that there is an open-source, and I hope that members of the community could also benefit from this

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/   does this help? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, it didnt help ;-( have you had any luck?